# Distribute N bits of information in M bits random messages

Tags: probability, information-theory

I am trying to dilute $N$ bits of information in a randomized message of size $M$.

Given that I know the location of the bits I want to conserve the most.
The way I picture this possible is to take each individual bit $b$ and dedicate to him $p$ bit with $p < 1$ known. So I want to get a Bernoulli trial with probability $x$ such that it would take $1/p$ trials to retrieve the bit $b$.

To rephrase my question and give examples I need to find the odd $x$ of flipping $b$ such that:

- When I want to dedicate 1 bit to $b$, $x = 0$.
- When I want to dedicate 0 bit to $b$, $x = 0.5$.
- When I want to dedicate $0.5$ bit to $b$, it would take two samples to retrieve $b$. (Beyond a reasonable doubt, let's say at 95% certainty)

In that way I could distribute "flipping factor" to each of the $M$ bit of the message I want to send and get a message of size $M$ containing $N$ bits.

I have tried to read up on information theory and entropy of the binomial distribution. I get the feeling entropy as a concept describes the inverse behaviour I want. For example lower probability messages transmits the most information (and have the most entropy) whereas here, if a message has perfect 50/50 probability I want it to transmit no information ! I am not well versed in the subject so it is possible I just don't connect the dots.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by retrieving a bit or taking samples. The standard information theory model is that you have a message which gets sent through a noisy channel. I don’t understand what 0.5 bits means. Are you padding your message with noise or are you describing a machine?

Comment: I mean 0.5 bit in the sense that if I were to repeat this procedure multiple times you would only need to get two full size messages to figure the bits that were encoded with only 0.5 bits. So in theory if I gave every bit in $M$ a non zero portion of the $N$ bits (such that the sum is exactly $N$), given enough trial you could decode the original full size message.

I am not really padding the message with noise I want to artificially noise portion of the message, such that one communication only effectively transmit $N$ bits. @Eric

Comment: Sounds like you want an error correcting code +noise.